# How to add a multiselect field to system config field table?

Tags: magento-1, admin-panel, system-config, core-config-data

I want to add a table to a config section, where one column is a multiselect field.

Code is simliar to https://www.integer-net.com/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/, but **Magento** only supports select (not multiselect) fields.

[image]
<sup>Similar to this, just add mutliselect field instead of text field</sup>

---

**Any ideas how to solve it?**

*Btw ... I'm pretty sure that a working solution was already posted at github/gist a long time ago as a Hackathon project, but I can't find it anymore ...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so I'm just taking a wild guess.
The link you mentioned from integer-net explains how to use a select field using a class `Namespace_Module_Block_Config_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Country` as renderer.

Using the same example, just add a new method to the renderer class (mentioned above)

```
public function getExtraParams()
{
    return ' multiple="multiple" ';
}
```

On the other hand, this might not work since for multiple selects you have too have the input name like `name[]` instead of `name` so you can receive an array via post or get from it.

If it does not work try to replace

```
   $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Country'),
        'renderer' => $this->_getRenderer(),
    ));
```

with

```
   $this->addColumn('country_id[]', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Country'),
        'renderer' => $this->_getRenderer(),
    ));
```

Again, not sure this will work.
I'm just throwing out ideas that are simple to test and don't involve a lot of coding. Maybe you get lucky and one works.

---

**Update**

In the same class where you added the method `getExtraParams` try adding / changing the method `setInputName`.
Make it look like this:

```
public function setInputName($value)
{
    return $this->setName($value.'[]');
}
```

**second Update**

change the method `_prepareArrayRow` in your `shippingCosts` block (in the example) to this:

```
protected function _prepareArrayRow(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $countries = $row->getData('country_id');
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $row->setData(
            'option_extra_attr_' . $this->_getRenderer()
                ->calcOptionHash($country),
            'selected="selected"'
        );
    }
}
```

and it should work. And put back the column name from `country_id[]` to `country_id`.

Comment: +500 if this had worked out of the box!  __Good:__ multiselect field is displayed. __Bad:__ I can't save multiple values. Only lasted one is saved.  _`a:1:{s:18:"_1489342298412_412";a:2:{s:10:"country_id";s:2:"VN";s:11:"email_delay";s:3:"999";}}`_

Comment: I thought it might happen. Didn't it work with `category_id[]` ?

Comment: Was I typo. Still had `country_id` instead of `country_id[]`. But with adding `[]` fields get not rendered anymore.

Comment: @sv3n See my update. If that does not help, I will stop shooting in the dark and actually  try to reproduce it on Monday.

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer! __1.__ Fields are rendered again __2.__ data is saved correctly `a:1:{s:18:"_1489342298412_412";a:2:{s:10:"country_id";a:2:{i:0;s:2:"US";i:1;s:2:"VN";}s:11:"email_delay";s:3:"999";}}` __But:__ selected values aren't selected in admin config (this was one thing, that was definitly changed in this hackathron project code i remember)

Comment: I will try this on Monday. Until now I just did speculations. It's time to code :)

Comment: @sv3n Sorry I did not come back exactly monday, but I think I found it. Check my latest update.

Comment: Wow. It works. I'm happy :) **Thanks a lot.**